# Spliting multi-index indices around a given level

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a MultiIndex DataFrame like the following:

```
                   X         Y 
A    B                           
bar  one    0.717822 -0.421127 
     three -0.763407 -0.306909 
flux six   -1.504799  0.977983 
     three -0.202268  1.971939 
foo  five   1.715336 -0.157881 
     one    0.942614 -1.529973 
     two   -1.918896 -0.989882 
     two    0.434202  1.438424
```

I would like to create a new column `new`, so that, **within** each value of `A`, for half of the `B` entries, the column `new` is `H`, while for the other half, `new` is `L`.

I am looking for an answer that makes **no assumptions** about the location of the levels in the index (i.e. the solution should refer to levels by names).

In the example above, one possible such assignment would look like the following:

```
                   X         Y  new
A    B                           
bar  one    0.717822 -0.421127   H
     three -0.763407 -0.306909   L
flux six   -1.504799  0.977983   H
     three -0.202268  1.971939   L
foo  five   1.715336 -0.157881   H
     one    0.942614 -1.529973   H
     two   -1.918896 -0.989882   L
     two    0.434202  1.438424   L
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first created a series with a relative cumulative count within each group (grouped on level A), and then assigned "H"/"L" to the values below/above 0.5:

```
In [118]: s = df.groupby(level='A').cumcount() / df.groupby(level='A').size()

In [119]: df['new'] = 'H'

In [120]: df.loc[s>=0.5, 'new'] = 'L'
```

Update: the division does not seem to work with pandas 0.13.1 (but does with master/0.14). Instead you can use the `div` method and explicitely specify the level:

```
s = df.groupby(level='A').cumcount().div(df.groupby(level='A').size(), level='A')
```